# using an index into pointer addresses results in address zero

Tags: c, pointers, buffer

I'm writing an MCU application that loads serial data in from a UART and writes it to flash.  I'm using two buffers in a "store the incoming data in the empty buffer while we empty the full one" (aka "buffer toggling") methodology. The UART receive was written in such a way that the "store the incoming data" should store directly into the buffer at the proper byte location.  The buffers are 512 bytes long because each flash sector is 512 bytes long.

I wanted to use indices: one index that indicates which buffer is being loaded; a two-index array that has the addresses of the first byte of each buffer; and an index that has the offset within the buffer (0-511) of the actual target storage address for the incoming byte. The code was designed to use the "which buffer?" index to obtain the address of the to-be-loaded buffer, then add to that the offset within the buffer, and that should be all that is needed.  I'm trying to keep path lengths short in order to do everything possible to avoid buffer overrun.

However, I am somewhat of a n00b at C.  While inspection of the two aFlashBuffahs shows me the correct addresses of the two buffers, bFlashBuffah0[512] and bFlashBuffah1[512], it appears that the code below causes the pointer to the buffer (aFlashBuffahInUse) to be zero, and thus the expression *(aFlashBuffahInUse+hBuffahByteInUse) to be bogus.

```
uint32_t    fFlashEndingAddress     = 0x2765A6;
uint8_t     iBuffahInUse            = 0;
uint16_t    hBuffahByteInUse        = 0;
uint16_t    *aFlashBuffahInUse;
uint16_t    *aFlashBuffahs[2];
uint8_t     bFlashBuffah0[512];
uint8_t     bFlashBuffah1[512];

aFlashBuffahs[0] = &bFlashBuffah0;
aFlashBuffahs[1] = &bFlashBuffah1;

iBuffahInUse      = 0;
aFlashBuffahInUse = aFlashBuffahs[iBuffahInUse];
hBuffahByteInUse  = 0;

for (i = 0; i < fFlashEndingAddress; i++) {
    *(aFlashBuffahInUse+hBuffahByteInUse) = usart_getchar(UASRT_SERIAL);
```

If someone could please lmk where I've erred, I would appreciate it. Tia!

Comment: when asking about a runtime problem,  post code that cleanly compiles, is short, and still shows the problem.  If the problem is about data, post the actual input data (a reasonable sample) and the actual output data (a reasonable sample).

Comment: I dont' see how your loop `for (i = 0; i < fFlashEndingAddress; i++)` can possibly work unless you swap buffers every 512 bytes.

Comment: You have not even used `i` to index anything, whatever the loop does, it writes every incoming byte to the same place.

Comment: the typical term is not `buffer toggling` but rather `double buffering`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

NOTE: in C, a reference to an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array, so lines like this: aFlashBuffahs[0] = &bFlashBuffah0; are getting the address of an address, the lines should be more like this: aFlashBuffahs[0] = bFlashBuffah0; Notice no extra & operator.

Suggest writing the code similar to:

```
uint32_t    fFlashEndingAddress     = 0x2765A6;
uint8_t     iBuffahInUse            = 0;
uint16_t    hBuffahByteInUse        = 0;
uint16_t    *aFlashBuffahInUse;
uint16_t    *aFlashBuffahs[2];
uint8_t     bFlashBuffah0[512];
uint8_t     bFlashBuffah1[512];

aFlashBuffahs[0] = bFlashBuffah0;  // <-- note change
aFlashBuffahs[1] = bFlashBuffah1;  // <-- note change

//iBuffahInUse      = 0;
//aFlashBuffahInUse = aFlashBuffahs[iBuffahInUse];
aFlashBuffahInUse = bFlashBuffah0; // <-- added
//hBuffahByteInUse  = 0;


for (i = 0; i < fFlashEndingAddress; i++) {
    *(aFlashBuffahInUse+hBuffahByteInUse) = usart_getchar(UASRT_SERIAL);
    hBuffahByteInUse++;
    if( 512 == hBuffahByteInUse )
    {
        hBuffahByteInUse = 0;
        // initiate processing of buffer (but do not do processing here)
        ....
        // swap buffers
        (aFlashBuffahInUse == bFlashBuffah0)? bFlashBuffah1 : bFlashBuffah0;
    }
```

ALSO:
The posted code contain several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.

Examples are: 0x2765A6, 2, 512

Suggest either use an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

It might also be mentioned that the posted code does not swap buffers when a buffer gets full.  I added that feature in my answer.

Comment: Suggest:  writing an interrupt handler that performs the code in the 'for()` code block.   That would make the overall flow much better and would not be 'eating' CPU cycles waiting for the next char to be available as in the 'usart_getchar()` function

Comment: "... reference to an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array" - Two wrong statements in one sentence (thress if we assume you mean the data-type "reference" and not mentioning the name - C has no reference type).

Comment: Writing to MCU Flash from an interrupt handler is likely a very bad idea. At best it stalles execution, at worst it crashes and corrupts Flash contents.

Comment: Thanks for all of the input - I appreciate it.  And my apologies on posting "abbreviated" code!

Comment: @Olaf,  No one said to write to flash from an interrupt handler.  All I said was the interrupt handler collects the data into the current buffer, and when that buffer is full to do two things: a) switch to other buffer b) trigger the background function that actually handles the data.

Comment: @Olaf, perhaps I verbalized it wrong.  However when the code says `aFlashBuffahInUse = bFlashBuffah0;` then the address of the first byte of the array `bFlashBuffah0` is assigned to the pointer: `aFlashBuffahInUse`.   Anything else read into my statement is not implied.

Comment: It still is wrong. If you don't want to be missunderstood, you should be clear. Arrays and pointers are the major cause of confusion for C beginners (and many who should know better).

Comment: @Olaf, then, please state how you would write the needed information that an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.

Comment: Well, the standard is very clear about _implicit conversion_ and when it is applied to an array and **when not**.